# Factorize $x^4 + x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x - 4$ showing all work

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring, quartics

Factorize showing all workings $x^4 + x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x - 4$.

I've attempted this question from the textbook "Core Maths for Advanced Level" by L. Bostock and S. Chandler and I'm having difficulty factorizing it. I got to the point where I know that $(x-2)$ is a factor and I tried solving for the co-efficients of $x^2$ and $x$ to have it factorization in the form $(x-b)(x^3 + cx^2 + dx + e)$, from which I was going to further factorize using the factor theorem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $x+2$ is also a factor

Comment: Why don't you just perform division?

Comment: For the fully generalized problem, I recommend [this video by Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc&vl=en-US).  It is a bit long, but it was the first time that an explanation of factoring a cubic made sense to me.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner that implies that one can recognize the $(x-2)$ and $(x+2)$ factors early on.  In the event that one doesn't spot any factors by inspection, the problem gets rather complicated.

Comment: @JMoravitz The rational root theorem is a good place to start

Comment: I appreciate the quick responses. Thanks all. I'll try the suggested methods y'all proposed.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4+x^3-3x^2-\color{blue}{4x}-4=(x^4-\color{red}{4x^2})+(x^3-\color{blue}{4x})+(\color{red}{x^2}-4)=\\=x^2(x^2-4)+x(x^2-4)+(x^2-4)=(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+x+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) ?

Let's start trying: $x=\pm1, \pm2, \pm4.$

You can easily deduce that, $x_1=2,x_2=-2$ are roots.

Then applying the method [Polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)

$$\begin{align} \dfrac {x^4 + x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x - 4}{(x-2)(x+2)}=  \dfrac {x^4 + x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x - 4}{x^2-4}=x^2+x+1 \end{align}$$

So, you get

$$\begin{align} P(x)=x^4 + x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x - 4=(x - 2) (x + 2) (x^2 + x + 1). \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
&x^4 + x^3 - 3x^2 - 4x - 4\\
=&x^4 + x^3 +x^2 - 4x^2 - 4x - 4\\
=&x^2(x^2+x+1)-4(x^2+x+1)\\
=&(x^2-4)(x^2+x+1)\\
=&(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+x+1)\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I like the following way:
$$x^4+x^3-3x^2-4x-4=\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{5}{2}\right)^2=$$
$$=(x^2-4)(x^2+x+1)=(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+x+1).$$
We can get this factoring by the following way.

For any real $k$ we have:
$$x^4+x^3-3x^2-4x-4=$$
$$=\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}x-k\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}x^2-k^2-2kx^2-kx-3x^2-4x-4=$$
$$=\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}x-k\right)^2-\left(\left(2k+\frac{13}{4}\right)+(k+4)x+k^2+4\right).$$
Now, we'll choose a value of $k$, for which $2k+\frac{13}{4}>0$ and
$$(k+4)^2-4\left(2k+\frac{13}{4}\right)(k^2+4)=0$$ or
$$2k^3+3k^2+6k+9=0$$ or
$$k^2(2k+3)+3(2k+3)=0$$ or
$$(2k+3)(k^2+3)=0,$$ which gives $k=-\frac{3}{2}$ and we got our factoring.

Comment: It's not clear to me how one could do the first step quickly?

Comment: @Ennar I added someting. See now.

Comment: Well, How did you guess that you would finally find $k$ independent of radicals?

Comment: @lone student If a priori our polynomial is a product of two quadratic polynomials with integer coefficients, so this method (Ferrari's method) always does not give radicals. By the way, in the general this method always gives factoring with radicals maybe.

Comment: This is a circular logic.You need to know beforehand.

Comment: +1 for learning something new :)

Comment: @lone student If the Ferrari's method does not give rational roots, so does not exist another method  which gives a factorization with integer coefficients. By the way, by this method we can factorize $x^4+2x^3+2$ easily. Try to use another method. Good luck!

Comment: "If a priori our polynomial is a product of two quadratic polynomials", What do you think about $x^4 + 4 x^3 + 5 x^2 + 3 x + 1$ ?

Comment: @lone student Your polynomial is not product of two quadratic polynomials with integer coefficients.   It gives a very ugly factorization. It's not so interesting, but it's possible.  There is a factor $x+1$. Try to factorize my polynomial. It's nice.

Comment: I mean if I understand correctly, you cannot apply this method unless you have an exact idea of ​​whether the multipliers are quadratic.Maybe if the polynomial is never factorization? If you cannot find $k$ in as radical, does this prove that the polynomial will not be factored?

Comment: @lone student You absolutely did not understand me. I say that this method always gives factoring on two quadratic polynomials. Also, in most cases I am trying to use this method. Try to solve my problem and you'll understand me, I think. Try $x^4+4x^3+2$. It's easier.

Comment: It always gives  factoring on two quadratic polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand you either. I mean, (I'll ask shorter). How do you know beforehand whether the factors of the polynomial you want to factorize are quadratic or cubic?

Comment: @lone student I don't want to think about a linear factor. It not always exists. $x^4+2x^3+2$ has no linear factor because this polynomial has no real roots. I'll say again. Any polynomial with fourth degree and with real coefficients we can factorize on two quadratic polynomials with real coefficients. We can make it always by the method, which you saw.

Comment: Now its clear for me. You mean fundamental theorem of algebra.  I was doubt that this method would provide direct convenience. I was talking about factoring the **rational coefficient** polynomial with only **rational coefficient** polynomial. The above method does not provide this always. I give an example. $x^4 + 4 x^3 + 5 x^2 + 3 x + 1$.  So I asked, "How do you know beforehand?".So the two of us were talking about different things. I was talking about rational factor multipliers.

Comment: @lone student The first thing, which we are doing, we are checking a rational roots. If the polynomial has no rational factorization, what you'll do? Sometimes it's better to use the Ferrari's method and not look for rational roots because these roots may be very very ugly.

Comment: It is not factorize with rational coefficient factors. I will apply the well-known method of Rene Descartes. Of course, the coefficients will not be rational. And probably this factoring does not promise us anything good.

Comment: The Decartes's rule it's something other. We can get a number of roots only. It can not help here. I need to go. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: No. With the Descartes method, you can always factorize any quartic  with product of  two quadratic polynomial independent of the coefficients are rational or not. (Thank you for the explanations too.)

Answer (score 0):

If you develop $(x-2)(x^3+cx^2+dx+e)=x^4+(c-2)x^3+(d-2c)x^2+(e-2d)x-2e$

Now identifying the coefficients you get

$\begin{cases}
c-2=1 & c=3\\
d-2c=-3 & d=2c-3=3 \\
e-2d=-4 & e=2d-4=2\end{cases}$

You now have to factorize $x^3+3x^2+3x+2$.

As indicated try first to find obvious solutions before going for Cardan formula.
If there are rational roots they should be in $$\pm\dfrac{\text{divisors of }a_0}{\text{divisors of }a_3}=\{-2,2,-1,1\}$$

And you find $-2$ as a new root.

Now another method to divide, add terms of higher degree until you get everything:

$\begin{align}
x^3+3x^2+3x+2 &=(x+2)(x^2+...)    &=x^3+2x^2+...\\
              &=(x+2)(x^2+x+...)  &=x^3+3x^2+2x+...\\
              &=(x+2)(x^2+x+1)    &=x^3+3x^2+3x+2
\end{align}$